# How to remove space after the first pattern in sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file

file.txt

```
Name-6.1.4_Float Time;453802;464204;466345 464481 466131  464283  465065 462561
Name-6.1.4_Logic Good Time;125896;145349;137303 131601  144520 132487  133884
```

I want to replace the spaces between the numerical value by `;` after the first semicolon `;` The spaces between the numerical value can have more than one space. Also on above `Name_Float Time` can be anything.

Expected Output:

```
Name-6.1.4_Float Time;453802;464204;466345;464481;466131;464283;465065;462561;
Name-6.1.4_Logic Good Time;125896;145349;137303;131601;144520;132487;133884;
```

Here what I have tried:

```
sed 's/ /;/g;s/;;/;/g;s/$/;/g' file.txt
```

Output:

```
Name-6.1.4_Float;Time;453802;464204;466345;464481;466131;464283;465065;462561;
Name-6.1.4_Logic;Good;Time;125896;145349;137303;131601;144520;132487;133884;
```

On above output, the spaces between the Name also get replaced by `;`. Please suggest me how to avoid the spaces between the name to get replaced by `;`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E ':a;s/(;[^ \t]+)[ \t]+/\1;/;ta' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Kdnke1)

**Details**

- `:a;` - label
- `s/(;[^ \t]+)[ \t]+/\1;`:

  - `(;[^ \t]+)` - find and *capture* into Group 1...

    - `;` - a `;` char
    - `[^ \t]+` - one or more chars other than space and tab
  - `[ \t]+` - 1 or more  space or tab chars are matched without capturing
- `\1;` - and replace with the Group 1 contents + a semi-colon after it
- `ta` - loop to `:a` if there was a match at the preceding iteration.

Comment: After executing your code, It is working fine, but I need to give more constraints. I am editing the question. Sorry for inconvienience!!

Comment: @Arya Try `sed -E ':a;s/(;[^ \t]+)[ \t]+/\1;/;ta' file`

Comment: @Arya If you need to have a `;` at the end, too, just pipe another `sed`: `sed -E ':a;s/(;[^ \t]+)[ \t]+/\1;/;ta' file | sed 's/;*$/;/' > outputfle`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/uihP9N).

Comment: In GNU sed you can use `\s` for whitespace and `\S` for its dual, so your solution becomes `sed  -E ':a;s/(;\S+)\s+/\1;/;ta' file`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {s=$1; $1=""; gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, OFS); $0= s $0 OFS} 1' file
```

```
Name-6.1.4_Float Time;453802;464204;466345;464481;466131;464283;465065;462561;
Name-6.1.4_Logic Good Time;125896;145349;137303;131601;144520;132487;133884;
```

---

Or, you may use `perl` with a support of `\G`

```
perl -pe 's/(^[^;]*|\G)[;\h]*(\b\d+|$)/$1;$2/g' file
```

```
Name-6.1.4_Float Time;453802;464204;466345;464481;466131;464283;465065;462561;
Name-6.1.4_Logic Good Time;125896;145349;137303;131601;144520;132487;133884;
```

[RegEx Demo & Details](https://regex101.com/r/yCWtzQ/2)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match

Answer (score 1):

With `Procedural Text Edit` you can do it like so:

```
forEach line {
    select (after ci ";") {
        findReplaceAll ci " " ";"
        removeDupeAdjacent ";"
    }
}
```