# Reasons for not using `\s` and `\S`

Tags: regex, sed

In GNU sed answers using the regular expression extensions `\s` which matches whitespace caracters and its dual `\S` which matches non-whitespace characters, seem to be shied from. Why is this?

Comment: Give some concrete examples, like links to those questions you're talking about.

Comment: @oguzismail [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884542/how-to-remove-space-after-the-first-pattern-in-sed/54884637?noredirect=1#comment96542759_54884637) particular question prompted my question. However I have been aware that many prominent answerers seem to be wary of their use.

Answer (score 2):

They're GNU-only and so non-portable to other seds, that's all. Just wrt matching white space and use of `-E` (idk about the rest), [the example you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884542/how-to-remove-space-after-the-first-pattern-in-sed/54884637?noredirect=1#comment96542759_54884637) would work with OSX/BSD sed or GNU sed as written, but if you used `\s` instead of `[ \t]` then it'd stop working in OSX/BSD sed. Personally I'd have used `[[:space:]]` for robustness and portability.

Comment: I like `[[:blank:]]` for `[ \t]`, whereas `[[:space:]]` contains a bunch more exotic ones (`\n`,`\r`, `\f`, `\v`).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I prefer `[[:space:]]` because then I don't have to think about whether I'm operating on multi-line or single-line text or whether or not any of the spaces I see are non-blank and non-tab. if I always use `[[:space:]]` in my code by default then  I **know** it's going to match all white space which is almost always what I want and I can use `[[:blank:]]` if I like for those very rare cases (which I personally don't think I've ever encountered yet) where I really do **only** want to match blanks and tabs.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for your answer, I am aware that regular expression extensions are specific to GNU but that is the aim of my question. As to why these extensions may cause problems when restricted to solutions using only GNU sed.

Comment: But the example you referenced doesn't claim to be GNU sed specific. AFAIK there's no issue with using them if you're already tied into GNU sed only constructs in the rest of your script as long as they do cover the chars you want to match (re `[[:blank:]]` vs `[[:space:]]`).

Comment: @EdMorton the crux of the reason for this question was prompted by comments made by myself and the OP (the OP perhaps thought better of s/he answers and removed them, hence the dangling question by left by me).