# Grep words with spaces

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a text file that contains quotes, comma and spaces.

```
"'x','a b c'"
"'x','a b c','1','2 3'"
"'x','a b c','22'"
"'x','a b z'"
"'x','s d 2'"
```

However, when I try using grep to pull the exact match, it doesn't display the results. Below is the command I'm trying to use.

```
grep -E "\"\'x\'\,\'a\s\+b\s\+c\'\"" test.txt
```

Expected output: "'x','a b c'"

Am I missing anything? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output you like to have.

Comment: Expected output: "'x','a b c'"

Comment: What do you like to search for to get that output?

Comment: You escaped `+` and it only matches  a literal plus in a POSIX ERE. Use `\s+` to match 1 or more whitespaces

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew POSIX ERE doesn't support \s

Comment: @oguzismail It works in Ubuntu 16.04, grep (GNU grep) 2.25.

Comment: Oh no, what I am saying is correct. ***You escaped + and it only matches a literal plus in a POSIX ERE.*** You  are now saying something I did not say. And `\s` works in Linux, GNU grep: see [**demo**](https://ideone.com/pJLrfo).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay then, just pointed out that \s won't work with all greps

Comment: @oguzismail I think [this is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887368/reasons-for-not-using-s-and-s) in our discussion :) It was asked due to my reaction to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884542/how-to-remove-space-after-the-first-pattern-in-sed/54884637?noredirect=1#comment96542563_54884637).

Answer (score 2):

You were close! Couple of notes:

- Don't use `\s`. It is a gnu extension, not available everywhere. It's better to use character classes `[[:space:]]`, or really just  match a space.
- The `\+` may be misleading - in `-E` mode, it matches a literal `+`, while without `-E` the `\+` matches one or more preceding characters. The escaping depends on the mode you are using.
- You don't need to escape everything! When in `"` doublequotes, escape doublequotes `"\""`, don't escape singlequotes and commas in doublequotes, `"\'\,"` is interpreted as just `"',"`.

If you meant only to match spaces with `grep -E`:

```
grep -E "\"'x','a +b +c'\""
```

This is simple enough without `-E`, just `\+` instead of `+`:

```
grep "\"'x','a \+b \+c'\""
```

I like to put things in front of `+` inside braces, helps me read:

```
grep "\"'x','a[ ]\+b[ ]\+c'\""
grep -E "\"'x','a[ ]+b[ ]+c'\""
```

If you want to match spaces and tabs between `a` and `b`, you can insert a literal tab character inside `[` `]` with `$'\t'`:

```
grep "\"'x','a[ "$'\t'"]\+b[ "$'\t'"]\+c'\""
grep -E "\"'x','a[ "$'\t'"]+b[ "$'\t'"]+c'\""
```

But with `grep -P` that would just become:

```
grep -P "\"'x','a[ \t]+b[ \t]+c'\""
```

But the best is to forget about `\s` and use character classes `[[:space:]]`:

```
grep "\"'x','a[[:space:]]\+b[[:space:]]\+c'\""
grep -E "\"'x','a[[:space:]]+b[[:space:]]+c'\""
```

Comment: Why do you suggest not to use `\s` if OP might in fact only use the regex with a GNU grep? It is not clear if OP has a GNU or any other grep, but I came to the conclusion that it makes no sense trying to come up with "generic" solutions for *NIX tools as there is always at least one environment where the solution does not work. If `\s` works for OP (same as for me) we can use it, why not? Besides, `grep -E "\"'x','a +b +c'\""` is not valid syntax in my Bash (`GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`). Do you have an idea why?

Comment: That is a valid point. Just tested and on alpine with busybox `\s` matches a space. `"\"'x','a +b +c'\""` - I just tested on my old machine with bash4.2.24(1) with GNUgrep2.13 and `grep -E "\"'x','a +b +c'\"" <<<"\"'x','a    b c'\""` works. No idea then.